# Application is null when using it in my dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an dll that have class Login and a method:

```
public class Login
{
    public Login()
    {
        Setting1 s1=(Setting1)Session["setting"];
        Setting2 s2=(Setting2)Application["setting"];//Application is null !
        ///using of my setting
    }
}
```

I have set Application with an object of `Setting` in `Global.asax`

It works properly for casting session.Code work properly when it is  on a class in my Webform application.

Comment: Try using `HttpContext.Current.Application`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
HttpContext.Current.Application
```

Instead of

```
Application
```

**Update**

Some times during the page life cycle it offen happens that some of the objects are not initialized properly for example in init method of page life cycle you wont get valid Request object but HttpContext.Current will provide you valid data.